# DateAdd function syntax error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, date

I have a date field named LAST, a short integer field named FRQ, and a date field named NEXT that I need to calculate. FRQ field is populated with frequency in months, with values that look like 6, 12, 24, etc.

I'm using ArcMap 10.8.2, and want to add the number of months from FRQ to the date in LAST, and get the result in NEXT.

When I r-click NEXT and open Field Calculator, choose the Date functions, DateAdd, and enter in the box under NEXT = the following:

```
DateAdd ( [LAST], [FRQ],"months" )
```

This gives me a syntax error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the VB Script `DateAdd` function with the Python parser. Either use a Python expression or change the parser to VB Script:

[image]

Comment: It worked. I was using VB Script Parser, but had the wrong sintax. I was using
DateAdd ( [LAST], [FRQ],"months" )

Your example showed me that I should use
DateAdd ( "m", [RTN_frq], [RTN_lst] ).

And that solved the problem. I wish there was a better documentation on the use of the function.

Thanks!!!!